# Custom Generic List Class - Function to add subclass object

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have the following class setup (I hope I haven't over simplified!)

```
public class Animal { }
public class Insect : Animal { }
public class Fly : Insect { }

public static class AnimalExtensions
{
    public static Insect CreateInsect(this string name)
    {
        if (name == "fly")
        {
            Fly fly = new();
            return new Fly();
        }
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In places in my code, I need to create list of these objects; maybe a list of Fly, more likely a list of Insect, but maybe a list of Animal.  All the lists share common properties (excluded for readability), so I've created a custom list class:

```
public class MyList<T> : Animal, IList<T> where T : Animal
{
    private List<T> _items { get; set; } = new();

    //...
    //IList<T> interface implemented
    //...
}
```

Now if I need a list of Insect I can do:

```
MyList<Insect> insects = new();
insects.Add("fly".CreateInsect());
```

**Problem**

I would like to simplify how items are added, and provide a way to set custom properties in a more consistent and reliable way...

I would like to add the following to the MyList class:

```
public void AddInsect(string insectName) /* where T : Insect */ //my imagined ideal fix!
{
    Insect insect = insectName.CreateInsect();
    _items.Add(insect); //** `cannot convert from 'Insect' to 'T'`
}
```

which could be called using the simpler `insects.AddInsect("fly");`

Any thoughts on how I can make the AddInsect function work?  I've tried all sorts of casting, but to no avail...

Comment: Add it as an extension method on `MyList<Insect>`? Anything wrong with that?

Comment: Maybe that is the only and sensible answer; I was hoping to make it more 'formal', but not sure what I mean by that :D

Comment: Oh I do know!  I want to make the IList `Add` method Obsolete to force use of the AddXXX functions; as an extension it's just a bit messy

Comment: That sounds like you need a new `MyListOfInsects` class inheriting from `MyList<Insect>` - one subclass of each type of `Animal` you want. Then the `Add` method, or `_items`, can be `protected`. You can also make `MyList` abstract if you want, so that people are forced to use one of the subclasses.

Comment: `public class MyList<T> : Animal, ...` => `MyList<T>` **is** an `Animal` ? That feels wrong.

Comment: The runtime uses extension methods for this case. See e.g. some of the [extension methods on `Vector128`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.intrinsics.vector128?view=net-7.0)

Comment: @BenRobinson, you are trying (and failing) to reinvent Factory pattern. also do you realise that you create 2 Fly objects and discard one of them here: `Fly fly = new(); return new Fly();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MyList<T> : Animal, IList<T> where T : Animal
```

A List of animals *is not* an animal itself, it should be

```
public class MyList<T> : IList<T> where T : Animal
```

Now to the second problem:

```
public void AddInsect(string insectName) /* where T : Insect */ //my imagined ideal fix!
{
    Insect insect = insectName.CreateInsect();
    _items.Add(insect); //** `cannot convert from 'Insect' to 'T'`
}
```

You would need to put the `where T : Insect` on the class, you cannot add additional restrictions on member functions. You can however write and extension method for a specific generic type:

```
public static void AddInsect(this MyList<Insect> self, string insectName) 
{
    Insect insect = insectName.CreateInsect();
    self.Add(insect);
}
```

This obviously require that `MyList<T>` has an `Add(T item)` method.

Please note that it is fairly easy to write overly generic code, and eventually either get yourself into a logical contradiction, or a compiler limitation. In most cases you should simply use a `List<Animal>` or maybe `List<Insect>` collection. You should probably also read about [variance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/), since that is another common problem when working with generic lists and polymorphism.

Comment: Extensions is the way to go!